# updating sql query value with select statement

Tags: sql

I am trying to execute a query which is something like:

```
update table set column=(select column1 from table1);
```

I just want to store the value from other table to my column

but when i try my sql query it says

```
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

definitely this means my table1 contains more than 1 row so i want to know that is there any way to store data into column from other table with multiple row.

or basically saving content of other table as a text something like

```
 update table set column='Data in text from other table';
```

Comment: This is because your subquery `(select column1 from table1)` returns more than 1 row as the error message says. You can use `limit 0,1` to get it working. But if this your expected result, I cannot tell you.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a correlation clause:

```
update table
    set column = (select column1 from table1 where table.col = table1.col);
```

You need to decide what column(s) are used for the correlation.

Comment: i want to add all columns not only one column i want all data from table is this possible

Answer (score 0):

it will work as  i am getting your requirement.Please let me know if your requirement is other i ll make changes in query

```
update table_name t1
inner join table1 t2 on t1.id =t2.id
set column =column1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your nested query returns multiple rows so you encountered this error.
Try in this way

```
UPDATE FirstTable
SET FirstTable.ColumnName =tbl2.ColumnName 
FROM SecondTable tbl2 WHERE tbl2.Id = FirstTable.Id
```

There should be a common id or something that will help to find exact row.